# Can't connect to my rbsoft SMS gateway database after moving website hosting - how to fix?

Tags: database, sms-gateway

i am getting these 2 errors when i tried to restore my rbsoft gateway

Warning: mysqli::_*construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'u1762128****'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/u651206305/domains/****.com/public_html/controller/MysqliDb.php on line 324

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Connect Error 1045: Access denied for user 'u176742128_s***'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/u6512065/domains/****.com/public_html/controller/MysqliDb.php:327 Stack trace: #0 /home/u651206305/domains/****.com/public_html/controller/MysqliDb.php(416): MysqliDb->connect('default') #1 /home/u6512063/domains/****.com/public_html/controller/MysqliDb.php(1993): MysqliDb->mysqli() #2 /home/u65120635/domains/****.com/public_html/controller/MysqliDb.php(1599): MysqliDb->_prepareQuery() #3 /home/u651206305/domains/****.com/public_html/controller/MysqliDb.php(739): MysqliDb->_buildQuery(NULL) #4 /home/u6512063/domains/****.com/public_html/controller/Entity.php(88): MysqliDb->get('Setting', NULL, Array) #5 /home/u651206305/domains/****.com/public_html/model/Setting.php(52): Entity::read_all() #6 /home/u651206305/domains/****.com/public_html/model/Setting.php(69): Setting::all() #7 /home/u651206305/domains/****.comm/public_html/includes/set-language.php(34): Setting::get('def in /home/u651206305/domains/****.com/public_html/controller/MysqliDb.php on line 327

pretty sure its bc i couldn't update the sql database like in step 4 here
https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/7238400-moving-a-website-to-another-hosting-plan-keeping-the-same-domain#h_8122fc21d5

that file isnt in my public_html,

can anyone help?

search files and videos

Comment: First please fix formatting in your question (at least put the error log into a code block). The problem seems to be that your application does not use correct username/password to connect to the database. You may have a better chance that someone will help you if you mention your framework and hosting name in the title of your post.